# Why is the findIndex method showing second occurance too?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Basically the idea is that my code chooses a random element from an array. That element is the `arr[i].answer` and is placed at the end of that array. Then i want to make the first occurrence of that answer as an `*`. I used the findIndex method as i thought that the first occurrence of my answer will become the `*` however both first occurrence and the last element have become an asterix.

Here is the code

```
arr.forEach(element => {
              arr[i].answer = arr[i].sequence[rndElement];
              arr[i].sequence[arr[i].sequence.length - 1] = arr[i].answer;

              function isFirst(element, index, array) {
                return element === arr[i].answer;
                }

                let index = arr[i].sequence.findIndex(isFirst);
                arr[i].sequence[index] = "*";

              
          });
```

Above is the necessary code, below is all the code for reference

```
const arr = [];
    const input = document.getElementById('answer').value;
    const rndElement = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);


    function displaySeq() {
        var i = 0;
        while (arr.length < 21) {
            const rndInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
            const iterator = Math.floor(Math.random() * (8 - 3 + 1)) + 3;
          arr[i] = {
              sequence: [rndInt],
              answer: 7,
              guess: []
          };

          let j = iterator;
          while (arr[i].sequence.length < 7) {
              arr[i].sequence.push(rndInt + j);
              j+=iterator;
          }

        arr.forEach(element => {
              arr[i].answer = arr[i].sequence[rndElement];
              arr[i].sequence[arr[i].sequence.length - 1] = arr[i].answer;

              function isFirst(element, index, array) {
                return element === arr[i].answer;
                }

                let index = arr[i].sequence.findIndex(isFirst);
                arr[i].sequence[index] = "*";

              
          });
          i++;

       }  
        console.log(arr);
    }
```

Comment: `arr.forEach(element => {` what is the purpose of having a loop here? You're running the same code for each element in your array, each time, updating the same object in your `arr`. The first time it runs, you update `arr[i].sequence[index] = "*";`, where `index` is the first occurrence, the next time it runs, `index` will be the next occurrence, as the first occurrence was changed to `"*"` in the previous iteration. Seems like you might not need this loop, but it is also difficult to tell what your code is trying to do. It also seems like you might be able to do `index = rndElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me prove that `findIndex` works like you expect:

```js
console.log([2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1].findIndex(item => item === 1))
```

Now, let's see what happens if you repeatedly apply `findIndex` while replacing your items:

```js
let foo = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]

for (let element of foo) {
    foo[foo.findIndex(item => item === element)] = "*";
}

console.log(foo);
```

So, how do you avoid overriding items that were overriden:

```js
let foo = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2];
let replacedItems = [];

for (let element of foo) {
    if (replacedItems.indexOf(element) < 0) {
        replacedItems.push(element);
        foo[foo.findIndex(item => item === element)] = "*";
    }
}

console.log(foo);
```

So, what is the problem that you have? The problem is that you replace your item with * and then search for the same item in the same array when it was already replaced at its former first index, so it's current first index is at a higher position, particularly the last one in your example.

What was the solution? We keep track of the item whose index was already found and avoid doing similar replaces.